# Custom Styled Checkbox with KnockoutJS does not respond to data-bind 'checked'

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, knockout.js

I have an advanced checkbox which is checked or unchecked based on initial data, and then it also responds when the user manually checks or unchecks it. Previously for my more primitive checkboxes, I really enjoyed using the checkboxes from [here](http://vsn4ik.github.io/bootstrap-checkbox/).

The only problem is that it doesn't work properly with Knockout. Notice how the checkbox doesn't respond when the custom checkbox is initialized. But if you remove this code from the bottom of the JavaScript, it works as expected.

```
// INITIALIZE CHECKBOX
$('#witnessSlider').checkboxpicker();
```

Here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/maxgrr/r23q740u/1/

This could also apply to various other types of custom checkboxes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're introducing a custom plugin that is transforming your native checkbox into some more complex structure, the built-in `checked` binding-handler is no longer able to detect changes because it was meant to work with `this.checked` of the native `<input type="checkbox" />` element (that is now hidden).

So, you need a more plugin-aware handler that will be able to update the view-model when the custom checkbox is mutated and also update the plugin when the model changes.

The following `checkboxpicker` handler does just that: the `init` function is called only once to setup the plugin, set its initial state according to the current view-model state (the value of the `wereThereAnyWitnesses`) and registering a listener (`change`) to any future changes that will then update the view-model.

The `update` function is called each time the view-model changes and is responsible of updating the custom checkbox state accordingly.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.checkboxpicker =
{
    init: function(element, valueAccessor){
        var val = valueAccessor();
        $(element).checkboxpicker().prop('checked', val()).change(function() {
            val(this.checked);
        });
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var val = valueAccessor();
        $(element).prop('checked', val());
    }
};
```

And in your HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkboxpicker: wereThereAnyWitnesses" />
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r23q740u/15/)

Comment: Once again I don't quite understand all of the features of your solution, so any inline comments are appreciated --  it could also help future readers. Other than that, once again you have crafted another amazing solution. This is perfect. You really know your way around the advanced functionalities of Knockout, unlike me. Thanks so much.

Comment: As a side-note, it could also be done using this simple line: `$('#witnessSlider').checkboxpicker().change(function() { murderCaseModel.wereThereAnyWitnesses(this.checked); });` (http://jsfiddle.net/r23q740u/16/). The problem is that upon confirming witnesses removal, if you hit 'cancel', the checkbox would still be checked, so I thought the custom binding-handler way is cleaner.

Comment: I agree; the custom binding-handler is the better solution, but that little snippet of code is useful for other applications, I'm sure! Thanks again!

Comment: Dude, thanks. Too late to save me from a headache, but this is an awesome solution, and just HAPPENS to be the exact library I'm using (bootstrap-checkbox) :D This needs more up-votes.